# What happens to upgraded users of an APK if I deactivate

Tags: android, google-play

I am not happy with the current version of my app in the Play Store.  I would like to disable it (for now).

Q:  If I disable it, are the users who already upgraded to the new version eventually downgraded to the older (re-activated) version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they stay on the last published version as far as I'm aware. People who have installed the version you are not happy with will keep having it even after you deactivate.

**There is no downgrade or "revert to previous" process.**

If you're unhappy, best thing to do if possible it to post an update/fixed version before you deactivate.

Edit: Can't find any official info but found someone else who agrees (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493065/833647).

I speak from experience of doing exactly what you describe :)

Comment: I actually like them to stay on the last published version.  I am looking for confirmation that is what happens.  Downgrading is mostly messy (most devs are happiest failing forward).

Comment: Deactivating just means no new people get it. People who already have it will stay on the version you are not happy with.

Comment: That is actually the functionality I want.  Just curious, have you personally confirmed this?  I am too worried to try this on my Prod APKs.  Marked your answer correct regardless (mostly because I like your last name ;-) ).

Comment: Haha thanks :) Yes I can personally confirm that deactivating simply ensures it doesn't show up in any listing and is not available to new users. Existing users are unaffected - nothing happens for them, they stay on whatever version they are on.

Comment: I have a single app codebase published under 27 client brands.  Falling forward instead of falling back is a serious chunk of work.  Yuck.

Comment: Can existing app users rate the app after you deactivate it?