# What happens after I unpublish an app from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

If I unpublish an android app from the market, will it get automatically deleted from users' phone? or will they just not get updates anymore?

And if I want it to get deleted, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not delete app from user's devices. It will be deleted from playstore only.

> if app is unpublished then is will not be available for download, will
>   not appear in search results, cannot installed. No details information
>   from Play can be received even with direct URL. Unpublishing does not
>   affect existing installations though and existing users still would
>   get update if they are on older version.
>
> And you cannot have another application with the same package name, no
>   matter what.

check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493065/3134215)

Comment: ok, but can I publish an invalidating update (that would stop the operation of the app), wait for most users to update and then unpublish it.

Answer (score 0):

By unpublishing your app from the play store, the app installed in the devices will not be deleted unless the users uninstall them from their devices.

Answer (score 0):

Removing an app from the playstore will literally remove it from the playstore. If you have it installed its up to the user whether to remove it or not from their phones. Kinda like Flappy Birds.

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete app from play store, you can only unpublish it.