# Is it possible remove temporarily an app from Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app in Google Play a few months ago. That app have some downloads and data from users in Console Google. I will release a new version, but while I'm finishing, I want remove it temporarily - keeping all that data and download numbers. Is it possible or when I cancel the publish all data will be deleted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please note that you unpublish (and this means just what name says, nothing more) not just APK - you hide all related stuff (app's page in Google Play etc). To end user it looks like the app is gone. For you - it is still in your console, you can edit description, images, see comments, stats or update APKs etc., but unless you publish it again, nobody will see these changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493065/7303462

Answer (score 3):

You could do that by unpublishing your app. You can re-publish it by installing a newer apk of the app and all the data will remain the same, you'd not loose any of it.

PS: You cannot delete an app from your account. Published and unpublished apps will remain in your account.

Comment: No is the wrong answer. It is possible. It is just a different word which he didn't know : )

Comment: When did he ask to remove it from Console?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2022 :**

You can go to "Google play console -> Release -> Setup -> Advanced Settings", but as google says :

**Unpublished**: New users cannot find and install your app. Existing users can still find it and will receive updates.

**Published**: New users can find and install your app

I found a solution so that you can restrict the region of your app if you do not want to delete and republish it. This prevents even existing users from finding your app. In the published list of your app, you should keep at least one country, and you can select the country with the lowest downloads.