# How much time Google takes to unpublish an GSuite marketplace app from Chrome web store developer dashboard

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, google-workspace

Its been three weeks my app (GSuite spreadsheet add-on) is in "Pending Review" state after unpublishing it through chrome web store developer dashboard. 
I also don't know why it is visible in marketplace as well when I already requested Google for unpublishing this item.

Query: Its already three weeks gone, any idea how much max time Google takes to unpublish an GSuite marketplace app from Chrome web store developer dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493027/what-happens-when-i-unpublish-an-app-from-the-google-play-market) about the unpublished apps in web store.

See this [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493065/8342742) from the post:

> if app is unpublished then is will not be available for download, will
>   not appear in in-store search results, and simply cannot be installed
>   from store. No details information from Google Play can be received
>   even with direct URL to the application. Unpublishing however does not
>   affect existing installations (so apps will not be automatically
>   removed from any device that got it installed already). Also existing
>   users still would be able to update if they are on older version.
>
> And you cannot have another application with the same package name, no
>   matter what.
>
> EDIT
>
> Please note that you unpublish (and this means just what name says,
>   nothing more) not just APK - you hide all related stuff (app's page in
>   Google Play etc). To end user it looks like the app is gone. For you -
>   it is still in your console, you can edit description, images, see
>   comments, stats or update APKs etc., but unless you publish it again,
>   nobody will see these changes.

Comment: I am talking about GSuite marketplace apps not Google android play store apps.